# vim/regex: replace everything between fourth and fifth semicolon

Tags: regex, bash, vim

I've found a variety of similar questions but I'm struggling to combine them together to solve my particular case. I have a number of very similar large text files and I want to be able to replace values between the fourth and fifth semicolons.

Each file is filled with hundreds of lines that look like this:

```
ABC  ;1  ;0  ;36.  ;0.   ;0.   ;0!
DEF  ;1  ;0  ;42.  ;0.47 ;0.47 ;0!
```

My plan is to create a bash script than can go through each file and replace particular values.

For instance, I want to replace the "0." after the fourth semicolon with "0.66" in the first line. I also want to replace the "0.47" after the fourth semicolon with "0.99" in the second line.

In other words, I want this:

```
ABC  ;1  ;0  ;36.  ;0.   ;0.   ;0!
DEF  ;1  ;0  ;42.  ;0.47 ;0.47 ;0!
```

To become this:

```
ABC  ;1  ;0  ;36.  ;0.66 ;0.   ;0!
DEF  ;1  ;0  ;42.  ;0.99 ;0.47 ;0!
```

Some complications:

1. this is a messy file with various amounts of white space (spaces and tabs) between the semicolons
2. sometimes the numbers between semicolons are integers (e.g. 0) and sometimes they are decimals (e.g. "0." or "0.1701")

So in reality, the lines can look more like this:

```
ABC  ;1  ;0    ;36.  ;0;0.;0!
DEF  ;1;0  ;42.  ;0.47     ;0.47       ;0!
```

Overall I don't really care about the 'messiness' of the file. I just want to be able to have a regex command that I can use to find and replace values between particular pairs of semicolons for individual lines.

Comment: Where do the values `0.66` & `0.99` come from?

Comment: A variety of sources, many of which I'll have to gather manually.

Comment: So, you want to change arbitrary columns on arbitrary lines with arbitrary data. That's a no. When you can state clear rules for how to select columns and lines and then select the data to put there, then yes, we can figure out systematic commands to accomplish it, but until you can define specs for each set of conditions, be prepared to do a lot of button-poking in vi. That said - `sed` can use line numbers or pattern matching to select lines if you can specify what applies to each. Regexes can select particular fields and replace with acquired values on those blessed lines. Just need specs.

Comment: That's not the case and I don't know how you came to that conclusion. In a large number of files that are very similar to one another, I want to be able to run a script that can find the line that starts with ABC and change the fourth column to X. Also find the line that starts with DEF and change the fourth column to Y. I am used to extensive "button-poking in vi" but this particular case is a sequence of repeat changes under the same conditions in multiples files. What Tim has helped me with below has gotten me almost 90% there and I am very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `sed -E`:

```
's/(?<=[\w\s]+(?:;[0-9\s\.]+){3};)[0-9\.]+/0.66/g'
```

**Explanation**

`(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind, which matches only when the preceding characters match the pattern inside the lookbehind

`[\w\s]+` matches one or more letters, underscores, or spaces

`(?:)` is a non-capture group, allowing patterns to be grouped without capturing them

`;[0-9\s\.]+` will match a semicolon followed by one or more digits, spaces, or periods

`{3}` that entire pattern will match exactly 3 times

`[0-9\.]+` matches one or more digits or periods

Comment: `sed` does not have the `\d` shortcut for `[0-9]`. And `+` needs to be `\+` for it to have the 'one or more' meaning (unless `sed` is called with `-E`).

Comment: @Marth Good catch - fixed!

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with sed. Do you mean this:

sed -E '(?<=[\w\s]+(?:;[0-9\s\.]+){3};)[0-9\.]+0.66' ?

Comment: Or could you parse that command a little for me? How to I tell it to identify the line that starts with 'ABC'? Which part specifies after the forth semicolon?

Comment: You want to do a substitution with `sed`, which would look like:  `sed -E 's/(?<=[\w\s]+(?:;[0-9\s\.]+){3};)[0-9\.]+/0.66/g'`

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I still can't tell where or how it identifies the pattern at the beginning of the line? If I want this to work only for the line that starts with 'ABC', how to I specify that?

Comment: it won't change a line where the pattern doesn't match, but you can also tell it to ONLY do lines based on matching things that don't even have to be part of the substitution. c.f. [the sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: I'm going to say that Tim answered my question because he has gotten me 90% of the way and I'll need to get more familiar with sed to match my specific case. Thanks for your help!